# How to create your own link variable in apex oracle?

Tags: html, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex

And where and how in the application to create your P1_HELP variable so that it would be possible to use, for example, src = "# P1__HElP #" in the HTML code without bothering with javascript?

Answer (score 2):

If I understood what you are asking, then the

- "link variable" would probably be an **application item** (located in Shared Components)
- item can be created anywhere (on a page, or as an application item); reference it as (for example)

  ```
  title=&P1_HELP.
  ```

  (note both leading `&` and trailing `.`)

Comment: Something for XSS awareness https://roelhartman.blogspot.com/2014/09/apex-5-new-substitution-syntax-features.html though even using a classic report filtered here by :APP_PAGE_ID wouldn't be out of the question.